# Determine the value of Ic (sat) and the value of Rb in a simple circuit

Tags: transistors

I need help with my homework I do not understand how to find the resistance for the Rb in the for this problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcjXHD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the question:

In this circuit, the transistor has a gain of 80 and a voltage Vce (sat) of 0.1V Rb is adjusted to have a transistor saturation. Determine the value of Ic (sat) and the value of Rb. Vcc=25V

I found Icsat with the following calculation.

Since the voltage is the same in parallel circuit I know that Vin = Vcc

Vin -Vcc-Vce(SAT)=0

1. 25-RcIc-0,1=0
2. 25-220Ic-0,1=0
3. -220Ic=-24,9
4. Ic=0,113A
5. =113mA

Now the second steps us to find Rb how can I do so?

Comment: Could you please update the schematic with the right nodes and values (use either R2 or Rc) so it matches your equations?

Comment: It is my first time using the schematic tool I did not know I could change the name of the  resistors thank you for the information.

Comment: _I know that Vin = Vcc_  and _[..]and a voltage Vce (sat) of 0.1V_ conflicts with _Vin -Vcc-Vce(SAT)=0_ . Because Vin-Vin-0.1V =/= 0V.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your circuit redrawn with all relevant information, in a form which will make analysis much easier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFhIDb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We use these additional facts:

- \$V_{CE(SAT)} = 0.1\;\text{V}\$
- The transistor is *just* saturated.

Start with the emitter voltage. It's connected to ground, so we can state:

$$V_E = 0\;\text{V}$$

The transistor is saturated, so the potential difference between its emitter and collector is 0.1 V. In other words, the collector voltage is 0.1 V *higher* than its emitter:

$$V_C = V_E + 0.1\;\text{V} = 0\;\text{V} + 0.1\;\text{V} = 0.1\;\text{V}$$

Saturation collector current will be the current through \$R_C\$ in this saturated state. Note that here we use the known "absolute" potentials at either end of \$R_C\$ to calculate the voltage across it, \$V_{CC} - V_C\$. By Ohm's law \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$ applied to \$R_C\$:

$$ I_{C(SAT)} = \frac{V_{CC} - V_C}{R_C} = \frac{25\,\text{V}-0.1\,\text{V}}{220\,\Omega} = \frac{24.9\,\text{V}}{220\,\Omega} = 113\,\text{mA}$$

Now we turn our attention to the base. When saturated, the transistor has a potential difference between base and emitter of 0.7 V. In other words, the
base voltage must be 0.7 V higher than the emitter:

$$ V_B = V_E + 0.7\;\text{V} = 0\;\text{V} + 0.7\;\text{V} = 0.7\;\text{V} $$

This transistor is *on the point of saturation*. We are only interested in the absolute minimum base current needed to achieve this, keeping in mind that the transistor will be saturated with *any amount of base current* greater than or equal to that minimum.

With \$I_{C(SAT)}\$ and ß known, we can apply the relationship \$I_C = \beta \times I_B \$ to find the corresponding \$I_{B(SAT)}\$:

$$ I_{B(SAT)} = \frac{I_{C(SAT)}}{\beta} = \frac{113\;\text{mA}}{80} = 1.41\;\text{mA}$$

We want to know what value of \$R_B\$ is needed to pass that base current. Again using the known potentials at either end of \$R_B\$, we can find the potential difference across it, and apply Ohm's law \$ R=\frac{V}{I}\$:

$$ R_B = \frac{V_{CC}-V_B}{I_{B(SAT)}} = \frac{25\;\text{V} - 0.7\;\text{V}}{1.41\;\text{mA}} = \frac{24.3\;\text{V}}{1.41\;\text{mA}} = 17.2\;\text{k}\Omega $$

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer but I am not sure why I have the correct answer. Here is what I did

1. Ic =BIb
2. 113mA = 80Ib
3. Ib =113mA/80
4. Ib = 0,0014125A = 1,41mA
5. V=RI
6. R = V/I
7. R= 25-0,7/1,141mA // Here is the part that I am confused why must I substract 25-0,7?
8. R = 17234ohm or 17,23kohm //wich is the correct answer

Comment: Equation 3 is written incorrect. It should be 113 mA/80. You use the this value correctly in equation 4.

Comment: Regarding equation 7: 0.7V is the basis-emmiter voltage (\$V_{BE}\$). So, right of resistor Rb is a voltage of 0.7V and left of Rb is 25V, the voltage across Rb becomes (25V-0.7V)